# Есть 2 слайдера, переключаются между собой кнопками. При загрузке страницы видно оба блока, а должен один

Tags: javascript

```
 <section class="reviews" id="reviews">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                <img src="img/reviews-title.svg" alt="" class="reviews__title">
                <p class="reviews__subtitle">Почитайте и посмотрите, что пишут о нас покупатели.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="reviews__cta d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <a class="reviews__cta-left">Письменные отзывы</a>
                    <a class="reviews__cta-right">Видео-отзывы</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row slider__wrapper-text active">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="slider__wrapper">
                    <div class="slider-text d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <div class="reviews__item">
                            <img src="img/reviews1.png" alt="" class="">
                            <p class="reviews__item-desc">Александра Шведова</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="reviews__item">
                            <img src="img/reviews2.png" alt="" class="">
                            <p class="reviews__item-desc">Вероника Маслова</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="reviews__item">
                            <img src="img/reviews2.png" alt="" class="">
                            <p class="reviews__item-desc">Александра Шведова</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="reviews__item">
                            <img src="img/reviews2.png" alt="" class="">
                            <p class="reviews__item-desc">Вероника Маслова</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="reviews__item">
                            <img src="img/reviews2.png" alt="" class="">
                            <p class="reviews__item-desc">Александра Шведова</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="reviews__item">
                            <img src="img/reviews2.png" alt="" class="">
                            <p class="reviews__item-desc">Вероника Маслова</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row slider__wrapper-video">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="slider__wrapper">
                    <div class="slider-video d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <div class="reviews__video-wrapper">
                            <div class="reviews__item reviews__item-video">
                                <div class="reviews__overlay"></div>
                                <img src="img/reviews-video1.jpg" alt="" class="">
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/btn_play.svg" alt="" class="reviews__play">
                        </div>
                        <div class="reviews__video-wrapper">
                            <div class="reviews__item reviews__item-video">
                                <div class="reviews__overlay"></div>
                                <img src="img/reviews-video2.jpg" alt="" class="">
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/btn_play.svg" alt="" class="reviews__play">
                        </div>
                        <div class="reviews__video-wrapper">
                            <div class="reviews__item reviews__item-video">
                                <div class="reviews__overlay"></div>
                                <img src="img/reviews-video1.jpg" alt="" class="">
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/btn_play.svg" alt="" class="reviews__play">
                        </div>
                        <div class="reviews__video-wrapper">
                            <div class="reviews__item reviews__item-video">
                                <div class="reviews__overlay"></div>
                                <img src="img/reviews-video2.jpg" alt="" class="">
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/btn_play.svg" alt="" class="reviews__play">
                        </div>
                        <div class="reviews__video-wrapper">
                            <div class="reviews__item reviews__item-video">
                                <div class="reviews__overlay"></div>
                                <img src="img/reviews-video1.jpg" alt="" class="">
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/btn_play.svg" alt="" class="reviews__play">
                        </div>
                        <div class="reviews__video-wrapper">
                            <div class="reviews__item reviews__item-video">
                                <div class="reviews__overlay"></div>
                                <img src="img/reviews-video2.jpg" alt="" class="">
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/btn_play.svg" alt="" class="reviews__play">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>



$(function () {
    
    const btnText = document.querySelector(".reviews__cta-left");
    const btnVideo = document.querySelector(".reviews__cta-right");
    const sliderText = document.querySelector(".slider__wrapper-video");
    const sliderVideo = document.querySelector(".slider__wrapper-text");
    
    

    btnVideo.addEventListener("click", function() {
        
        sliderText.classList.remove('d-none');
        // sliderText.classList.toggle('active');
        sliderVideo.classList.toggle('d-none')
    })
    btnText.addEventListener("click", function() {
        
        // sliderVideo.classList.add('d-none');
        sliderVideo.classList.toggle('active');
        sliderVideo.classList.remove('d-none');
        sliderText.classList.toggle('d-none')
    })

});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]